# UWP SwipeControl programmatic interaction

Tags: uwp

Is it possible to programmatically interact with a SwipeControl in UWP? I'm not seeing anything in the API, but I thought I'd see if anyone had a workaround.

Ideally, I'd like to essentially have keyboard shortcuts as my device has buttons. Keyboard-navigation to the SwipeControl will auto-display my Reveal Delete item, then the select key with perform the Delete.

Comment: Could you  explain to me what is `pre-swipe`

Comment: you can add delay in you current swipe OR execute your event after swipe ended

Comment: I've edited the question to add some clarity (I hope), @NicoZhu-MSFT)